# Отличия в способах моделирования деков

Tags: c++

Какие основные плюсы и минусы в моделировании дека (двусвязной очереди) на основе динамического массива? Двусвязного списка? Какой из них лучше?

Comment: обычно деку делают на базе `std::list<std::vector<T>>` А о Ваших вариантах я не слышал.

Comment: можно на базе виртуальной памяти сделать, работать будет хорошо, но много таких дек не создать.

Comment: на базе виртуальной памяти? это что то новенькое

Comment: Это что-то старенькое, ещё до 2000 года.

Comment: Покажите тогда "это старенькое". Мне просто уже интересно.